# I need an example of two non-isomorphic graphs with the same degree sequence.

Tags: graph-theory

I'm struggling to find two non-isomorphic graphs with the same degree sequence. The only method I have is trial and error but its yielding no results. Could someone please provide me with one. Or is there a easy, general way of coming up with examples.

NB: There are no no loops and at most one edge between any two vertices.

Comment: Your question is likely to be closed, not because it's so simple, but because you tell us nothing about your own struggle with the problem. What have you tried, what do you know about that could help you solve it?

Comment: By the way, do you know any graphs with the degree sequence $2,2,2,2,2,2$?

Comment: A cycle of length 6, $C_6$.

Comment: Good. Can you find another graph with the same degree sequence? One that is not connected?

Comment: Check http://mathworld.wolfram.com/topics/InteractiveDemonstrations.html, is this what you want?

Comment: Here's another idea. Start with $C_{10}$, a cycle of length $10$. Pick $3$ vertices at random, and add a leaf at each of the chosen vertices. There are $\binom{10}3==120$ different graphs you get in this way, and they all have the same degree sequence, namely $3,3,3,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1$. Of course some of them are isomorphic. **Are they all isomorphic?**

Comment: @bof I'm having difficulty coming up with a graph with degree sequence (2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2) which is not connected.

Comment: Can you find a graph with degree sequence $2,2,2$? If you can do that, you're halfway there.

Comment: By comparison of [A004251](//oeis.org/A004251) (number of graphical degree sequences) and [A000088](//oeis.org/A000088) (number of unlabelled graphs), the smallest examples have 5 vertices.

Comment: @PeterTaylor With that hint the simplest example seems to be $2,2,2,1,1$ which is the degree sequence of both $P_5$ and $K_3+K_2$.

Answer (score 5):

Let $G_1$ be a graph on 7 vertices that is a cycle. Then every vertex has degree 2. Let $G_2$ be a graph on the same 7 vertices that consists of precisely a vertex-disjoint 4-cycle and 3-cycle.

Then $G_1$ and $G_2$ have the same degree sequence; every vertex in $G_1$ has degree 2, and every vertex in $G_2$ also has degree 2. But are $G_1$ and $G_2$ isomorphic?